# What is GTP short for?

Tags: xilinx, transceiver

Xilinx uses so called "GTP Transceiver".

What is "GTP" short for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Gigabit Tranceiver Port](https://www.cesys.com/fileadmin/user_upload/service/FPGA/fpga%20boards%20%26%20modules/EFM-03/wp-101-EFM-03_-_Bit_Error_Rate_Tests_for_GTP.pdf), though wikipedia calls them MGTs, Multi Gigabit Tranceivers.

Comment: You were 6 seconds faster than me :-)

Comment: thank you :D  I only saw multi gigabit transceiver and was really unsure about the "p" xD

Comment: @t1fpga1 Given that there's a T in GTP, not sure why they tack 'Transceiver' on the end